# Eclipse not automatically starting the debug process of any app

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

In Eclipse not automatically starting the debug process of any app.
Waiting does not help. Icon lights red on start and debugging can start only manually by pressing the debug icon.
How to switch to usual autostart debugging?

[image: On start view]

Comment: Do you have "debuggable = true" in Android Manifest?

Comment: You press "run debug" and you have breakpoint no?